# Can functions return range in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

I want to two range values into a function and the function should return the larger range of the two. Can this be done in VHDL? By range I mean things like "7 downto 0". I want to use the returned range in declaration of an unsigned type.

Comment: Ranges are subtypes, and in VHDL, [sub]types aren't objects. Functions can return a record with two members ... can you make that work?

Comment: return record with two members?

Comment: You could just overload the function on return type.